# How can I store and use an array of different types derived from a common base type?

Tags: c#, types, polymorphism, radix

The title may need a bit of explanation, so here's what i'm trying to do:

- Common base type for UI elements, e.g. BasePanel
- More specialised elements can be defined, derived from BasePanel. For example, buttons and textboxes.
- A list of elements will be stored (of type BasePanel, so that specialised ones can be stored)
- This list will be looped through each frame and drawn (ignoring optimisation at the moment)

Example usage:

```
class UIButton : BasePanel
{
    public override void Draw(blah)
    {
        // Specialised drawing code
    }
}

foreach (BasePanel Element in StoredElements)
{
    Element.Draw(blah);
}
```

The problem with this is that it won't run the specialised code; it will just run the BasePanel code.
How can I improve this so that it will run the specialised code instead? Could I store the type of the element on the BasePanel, and then cast to it at runtime?

I've tried storing the BasePanel in a Container class which stores the original type, but I can't access the method - for example:

```
foreach(ElementContainer Container in StoredElements)
{
    Type t = Container.OriginalType;
    object el = Container.Element;

    Convert.ChangeType(el, t); //Can't use the returned object!

    t Element = (t)Convert.ChangeType(el, t); //This would be perfect, but it doesn't work.
}
```

Thanks for any help. This has made my brain explode.

Comment: can you check that BasePanel.Draw() is marked as virtual?

Comment: I don't get it. Why are you using an ElementContainer when you can just store the derived types?

Comment: @Maxim He only tried using a container to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works 100% for me with the following code:

```
class BasePanel
{
    public virtual void Draw(string blah)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base: " + blah);
    }
}

class UIButton : BasePanel
{
    public override void Draw(string blah)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UIButton: " + blah);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BasePanel> list = new List<BasePanel>();

        list.Add(new BasePanel());
        list.Add(new UIButton());
        list.Add(new BasePanel());
        list.Add(new UIButton());
        list.Add(new UIButton());

        foreach (var b in list)
        {
            b.Draw("just a string");
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with yours comes from your drawing code/logic.

Comment: Exactly right... This should work fine and is the correct way to store these types and invoke the method.

Comment: Thanks for this! I didn't realise you could store derived types in an array of base types and still retain the functions, etc. Is this part of polymorphism?

Comment: Yep. Any type can be implicitly converted to it's **base** (not the other way around).

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your example should work, but you could try extracting the Draw method (and any others you need for polymorphism) into an Inerface, then implementing the interface in each of the classes you want in the list.

Answer (score 0):

As DarkSquirrel stated, you can declare the parent class's functions as virtual. This should allow your code to run the specialized code

Comment: Thanks, essential piece of the puzzle

Answer (score 0):

What specialized type are you trying to execute

if you have

```
class Bar {
  public virtual void Draw() {
    DO STUFF!
  } 
}

class Foo : Bar {
  override public virtual Draw() {
    DO MORE STUFF!
  }
}
```

then somewhere in your code

```
Bar[] data = new Bar[] { new Foo(), new Bar()};
foreach (Bar elem in data) {
  elem.Draw();
}
```

The first elem will execute the overriden code in Foo for the first elem and the code in Bar for the second. Even if you cast an item down the code executed in the methods will still be the code in original object (and `elem.GetType()` will return Foo for a Foo type.