# How can I maintain a compile-time list of all types derived from a base class?

Tags: c++, boost

A similar question was asked about maintaining a runtime list of types for `c#`:

[How can I store and use an array of different types derived from a common base type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391501/how-can-i-store-and-use-an-array-of-different-types-derived-from-a-common-base-t)

Basically what I would like is to maintain a sequence of names of types that are derived from a common base class. I can achieve this at runtime by doing something like this:

```
std::vector v;

template <typename Derived>
class Base
{
  Base() { v.push_back(typeid(Derived).name())
};
```

This works if all derived classes are singletons, but with runtime overhead. If they weren't singletons I could add some checks to avoid duplication, but it still involves runtime cost. I was thinking of instead populating a type sequence such as a `boost::mpl_vector`:

```
class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {}
class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {}
class Derived3 : public Base<Derived3> {}

typedef boost::mpl::vector<
  Derived1,
  Derived2,
  Derived3> TypeSequence;
```

That works, but it means I have to manually maintain the list, which becomes a hassle for lots of types. I know I can automate this process using a horrid concoction of `boost preprocessor` loops but I was hoping to avoid macros to keep the codebase as maintainable as possible.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT: the solution must be entirely compile-time and must work even if none of the types are instantiated.**

Comment: @OMGtechy how do I make `push_back` run once at compile time?

Comment: I realise I misread your question, so I deleted the comment. Am working on a solution now.

Comment: There is no way to do that directly in C++, because in principle the set of "all types derived from Base" (optionally concrete), is open unless Base is final. That means it is always possible to define a new derived type in another translation-unit, or later in the same. Thus, you either have to manage the list manually, include a tool in the build-process extracting that list for you (complicated, you probably have to build it yourself), or you must be satisfied with a runtime solution like [OMGTechy shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25049670/3204551).

Comment: @Deduplicator I would be happy with a solution that restricts the list to the types within the given translation unit.

Comment: Looks like what you actually need is a tagged union, rather than inheritance. Check out `boost::variant`.

Comment: As a general rule, tagged unions are better when you have a fixed list of cases, but might need to define arbitrarily many functions to operate on these cases. On the other hand, inheritance is better when you have a fixed set of virtual member functions, but might need to add new cases.

Comment: what if you failed to compile if your manually maintained list was missing a type?

Comment: @Yakk that would be better than nothing. How would you implement this?

Comment: @arman make a list of types.  Have a crtp check that the passed type is on the list.  Require child classes to inherit via said crtp : instance blocked via friend and private ctors, nin0instance via coding standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: This answer was written before "the solution must be entirely compile-time and must work even if none of the types are instantiated." was added to the question.*

---

Although **this is not calculated at compile time, the name of each type is only added once**. You must create at least one instance of each type to work (aka. **types that are not instantiated will not be added to the container**)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct TypeBase{
    static std::vector<std::string> m_container;
};

std::vector<std::string> TypeBase::m_container;

template <typename DerivedType>
struct MyBase{
    MyBase(){
        static bool typeAdded = false;
        if(!typeAdded){
            typeAdded = true;
            // you may also want to demangle this name
            // take a look at boost/units/detail/utility.hpp
            TypeBase::m_container.push_back(typeid(DerivedType).name());
        }
    }    
};

struct Derived1 : public MyBase<Derived1>{

};

struct Derived2 : public MyBase<Derived2>{

};

struct Derived3 : public MyBase<Derived3>{

};

int main(){
    Derived1 a, b, c;
    Derived2 d, e, f;
    Derived3 g, h, i;

    for(std::string const & name : TypeBase::m_container){
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

**Using my compiler, this prints:**

```
struct Derived1
struct Derived2
struct Derived3
```

Comment: Runtime overhead is not an acceptable solution in this case. I need the solution to be entirely compile-time, and available before any of the classes are instantiated.

Comment: @Arman I'll see what I can do. Although the runtime overhead here would be tiny, I can understand the issue with types not being instantiated in time.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input. I updated the question to clarify that I need a compile-time solution.

Comment: @Arman my efforts so far indicate that you're not going to be able to do this **a)** without the usage of ghastly macros or **b)** the way I've outlined above. **Perhaps** you could by initializing a static data member with a lambda that adds the type name to a container, but my attempts at that so far have produced nothing.